# What is the unit of getrlimit?

Tags: linux, ulimit

Please help understand what is the unit of the [getrlimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html). I suppose it is byte but still it is a huge value.

```
>>> import resource
>>> soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS)
>>> soft
9223372036854775807
>>> hard
9223372036854775807
```

Comment: So did you read the link that you provided? It's right there, you want someone to copy the text from the link and post it on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rlim_t` is typically of type `unsigned integer`, and max/unlimited address space would be (2^64) - 1 on a 64 bit machine but however you see max limits as `9223372036854775807` on your machine. On CentOS/Ubuntu machines I see `RLIM_INFINITY` is set to `-1` and on MacOS it set `9223372036854775807` as constant representing unlimited limits.

[resource.RLIM_INFINITY](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.RLIM_INFINITY)
: Constant used to represent the limit for an unlimited resource.

On CentOS machine:

```
[root ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
[root ~]# ulimit -a | grep virtual
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
[root ~]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 30 2018, 23:45:53)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import resource
>>> resource.RLIM_INFINITY
-1
>>> soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS)
>>> soft
-1
>>> hard
-1
>>>
```